# Using REST Assured library for testing SOAP webservices

Tags: web-services, soapui, rest-assured

Is there a possibility of using REST Assured library for testing SOAP webservices?
I have a bunch of Test Suites in SOAP UI and I need to check if there is possibility of using REST Assured.
Can anyone suggest if this is possible?
Many thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST-assured does not have direct support for testing SOAP services, but it is possible by manually setting the `SOAPAction` and `Content-Type` headers and doing an HTTP `POST` etc. Then you can run XPath assertions on the response like you do for normal REST services in REST-assured.

I suggest you also evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as it has built-in support for SOAP, and also makes XML manipulation a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here I show you an example

Headers `SOAPAction` and `Content-Type` are **mandatory**. You need to find wich is the SOAPAction header in your case, sometimes is the next part of the last "/" in the url

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

XmlPath xmlPath;
Response response;

RestAssured.baseURI = "http://url";
response = 
                given()
                    .request().body("xml_text").headers("SOAPAction", "findSoapAction", "Content-Type", "text/xml").
                when()
                    .post("/path").
                then()
                    .assertThat()
                        .statusCode(200).extract().response();
System.out.println(response.asString());

//next we get the xmlPath of the response
xmlPath = response.xmlPath();
//and get the value of a node in the xml
String nodeValue= xmlPath.get("fatherNode.childNode");
System.out.println(nodeValue);
```

Elements in the code you should set:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://url";
```

Is the url where to make the request

```
given().request().body("xml_text")
```

The argument o body() is a string with the xml of the request

```
headers("SOAPAction", "findSoapAction", "Content-Type", "text/xml")
```

"findSoapAction" is a string with the value of the SOAPAction header you should guess, and "text/xml" is what you should set as Content-Type header.

```
xmlPath.get("fatherNode.childNode");
```

returns the value of the node. Example:

```
<fatherNode>
    <childNode>value of the node</childNode>
</fatherNode>
```

get("fatherNode.childNode") returns "value of the node"